# ajax not working on two different forms in same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i have two ajax scripts this is first

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#ajaxform").submit(function(e)
{
    $("#simple-msg").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");
    var postData ="";
    postData = $(this).serializeArray();
    var formURL = $(this).attr("action");
 alert("login");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
       //success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
       success:function() 
        {
     $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint"> Login Successfull </code></pre>');

        window.location = "Dealer/PostPropertyAdvanceDetails.php?login=successfull";


        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            $("#simple-msg").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint"> Wrong Username or password </code></pre>');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});

$("#simple-post").click(function()
{
    $("#ajaxform").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
});

});

</script>
```

this is second

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function()
{
$("#ajaxformReg").submit(function(e)
{
    $("#simple-msg1").html("<img src='loading.gif'/>");
    var postData ="";
    postData = $('#ajaxformReg').serializeArray();
    var formURL = $('#ajaxformReg').attr("action");
 alert("reg");
    $.ajax(
    {
        url : formURL,
        type: "POST",
        data : postData,
       //success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) 
       success:function() 
        {
     $("#simple-msg1").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint"> Register Successfull </code></pre>');

        window.location = "Dealer/PostPropertyAdvanceDetails.php?register=successfull";


        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) 
        {
            $("#simple-msg1").html('<pre><code class="prettyprint"> please fill all the details </code></pre>');
        }
    });
    e.preventDefault(); //STOP default action
});

$("#simple-post1").click(function()
{
    $("#ajaxformReg").submit(); //SUBMIT FORM
});

});

</script>
```

one for login and one for register login works fine.but when i click register both ajax scripts are called one by one..i want only register ajax script. i have used two different forms.

Comment: pls show your buttons

Comment: Might be a silly question but have you included the source to the jQuery library?

Comment: @AdRock his first ajax is working fine means it's already loaded

Comment: i have included lib.. button1 =<input type="button"  id="simple-post" value="Login"  width="150px" />  button2 =<input type="button"  id="simple-post1" value="Register"  width="150px" />

Comment: 1. Are you sure the formURL of #ajaxformReg is not the same as login page ?

Comment: 2. Is there any redirection from ajaxformReg to login page (and hence calls ajaxform) when you redirect to Dealer/PostPropertyAdvanceDetails.php ?

Comment: yes both are different 1st form = <form name="ajaxformReg" id="ajaxformReg" action="insertregistration.php" onSubmit="return ValidateFormFields();" method="POST"> 2nd form = <form name="ajaxform" id="ajaxform" action="AjaxCheckLoginPostProp.php" onSubmit="return ValidateFormFields();" method="POST">

Comment: @deepak show your full code i means forms... no one will steal your code

Comment: if div is not properly closed does it matter..

Comment: my form is two large..cant paste here only 30000 is limited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check all divs are closed properly and make sure that forms are not nested